# creating more then one float menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following layout:

---

### MENU BAR: zindex:50 - Fixed (content below scrolls under)

---

Picture: zindex:0 - (HEADER scrolls over)

---

### HEADER: zindex:1 - (scrolls over picture, then under MENU BAR)

---

### MENU BAR 2: zindex:1 - (scrolls over picture, then under MENU BAR)

---

PAGE BODY: zindex:1 (scrolls over picture, then under MENU BAR)

---

That's how it currently works but would like get HEADER and MENU BAR 2, to slide up as normal but then stop and become fixed when header reaches MENU BAR.

I don't think it is possible in pure CSS burnt out trying.

**html:**

```
<div class="menu_bar"> Links </div>
<div class="picture"> <img src="/xxx/xxx.png"/> </div>
<div class="header"> HOMEPAGE </div>
<div class="menubar2"> Links </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menubar {height:30px; width:800px; background:#000; colour:#fff; z-index:50;}
.menubarfixed {position:fixed; height:30px; width:800px; background:#000; colour:#fff; z-index:50;}
.picture {z-index:0; top:0;}
.header  {margin-top:40px; height:30px; width:800px; background:#555; colour:#fff; z-index:1;}
.menubar2 {height:30px; width:800px; background:#000; colour:#fff; z-index:1;}
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML, CSS, and your attempts at trying. You might also do a search for "sticky nav CSS" for a large number of tutorials.

Comment: You haven't posted any code, so I can't provide feedback - but you're looking for sticky headers, a pretty common pattern. Look into [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/).

Comment: Updated it with a bit of code, will have a look into sticky nav.

Comment: Not seeing much on creating multiple headers. waypoints seems like a lot of extensions for something like this

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNapGG this is the closest but cant seem to make the header stay